# What happens to load bearing capacity during the plastic region for a ductile material?

Tags: structural-engineering, solid-mechanics

Attached is a picture of a typical isotropic ductile material. Can anyone please tell me what happens to the load bearing capacity in the structure in each of the sub-regions under plastic deformation, namely 'strain hardening' and 'necking'. Is the load taken by the structure the highest until it fails, or the load taken by the structure increases and then begins to decrease until in fails? What is the trend? And also, if the latter happens, then what is the reason behind it? Is it related to change in stiffness of the structure in any manner? [image]

Comment: You need to clarify whether your concern is a ductile material that subjects to tension, or compression (that produces bearing), as the strain-strain curve (provided) is usually obtained through the tension test, and it closely reflects the behavior of the material under compression only up to the proportional point.

Comment: Also note, in structural engineering, the highest load a structure can take without being identified as "failure" is the load (tension or compression) that produces a stress on the entire cross-sectional area just under the yield strength, or buckling strength, whichever is smaller. Therefore, the stress beyond yield, in general, has no practical meaning.

Answer (score 1):

from a practical standpoint, any loaded structure which contains a member which is in its *plastic region* has by definition *failed*. It is no longer referred to as a structure, but instead as a *mechanism* containing *hinges* and undergoing *collapse*.

Answer (score 0):

For members under tensile stress, one can load them up to the ultimate strength point on your diagram, not advisable though.

And the deformation at any point is as shown, first linear than a flatter curve.

For very short members under compression, Young's modulus is the same, and loading past the ultimate load will cause the member to fail by plastic crushing.

As the length of the compression member goes through a range of intermediate to long, it fails first by elasto plastic and the elastic buckling. There you follow the applicable codes to calculate the maximum allowable loads.

Comment: For members under tensile stress, what exactly happens at the ultimate strength point? Will the structure automatically collaspe and fracture without making any change in the load applied, or there needs to be a change in the load (i.e. higher than the previously applied load at UTS) for it to undergo the phenomenon of necking?

Comment: at limet stress the structure is istill stable but critically fragile. past this point adding to the load will cause necking, which is self perpetual. meaning it needs not much more load to reduce the cross section to a point were concentration of stress in a small surface area will cause the section to rapture.

Comment: Yeah, understood. Thank you :)

Comment: But there is one more thing which bothers me. If the necking is triggered by adding a very small amount of load over the UTS point, then the load bearing capacity starts to decrease and at the same time, cross-sec area of necking region starts to thin as well. In true stress/strain curve, we see even beyond the UTS point, the stress keeps on increasing. Is this because the cross-sec area is decreasing at a faster rate than the decrease in the load taken by the structure?

Comment: Moreover, I believe that the engineering stress/strain curve as shared in my post (beyond UTS point) is valid for all of the structure, a ductile circular beam for instance. But the true stress/strain curve (beyond the UTS point) is only valid for the region which is undergoing necking only. What do you think about this statement?

Comment: can you provide something on my last two questions please?

Comment: yes, the cross-section is reduced as per Poisson's ratio even in the elastic range. it is reduced minimally at the elastic range but significantly past the ultimate range and of course necking. so if we calculate the stress as the cross-section gradually narrows get the real stress-strain curve.

Comment: Note, what you have provided is the "Engineering Stress-Strain Curve". For the actual design, once the "necking" starts, only the point of breaking has some engineering significance. The curve is idealized/simplified for engineering use, not for the study of material science.

Comment: To interpret the engineering stress-strain curve, we shall say - after the UTS the necking starts, the strain will continue to increase even with the externally applied stress decreases, this phenomenon will continue until breaking. However, on a true stress-strain curve, after the UTS, the externally applied stress remains constant but necking continues, thus the true stress is higher due to reduced crossectional area, and the increased internal stress will further increase the strain until breaking. So the true curve is more or less the mirror image of the engineering stress-strain curve.